# Object Pooling Design Pattern Close All Idle Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, object-pooling

This is a question about object pooling design pattern with MySql Connection. The intention of implementing this design pattern is to reuse the same connection/object when more than one instances needs to be created. Below code is a class of object pooling design pattern written in c#.

```
public abstract class ObjectPool<T>
{
    private long expirationTime;
    private Dictionary<T, long> Running, Idle;

    //Constructor
    public ObjectPool()
    {
        expirationTime = 30000; //30 seconds
        Running = new Dictionary<T, long>();
        Idle = new Dictionary<T, long>();
    }

    protected internal abstract T create();

    public abstract Boolean validate(T o);

    public abstract void expire(T o);

    public virtual T GetObject
    {
        get
        {
            //lock the first thread 
            //make sure first thread is executed before the second thread
            lock (this)
            {
                long now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                T t;
                if (Idle.Count > 0)
                {
                    IEnumerator<T> element = Idle.Keys.GetEnumerator();
                    while (element.MoveNext())
                    {
                        t = element.Current;

                        //unlocked[t] -> Get the VALUE asscoiated with the specified KEY
                        if ((now - Idle[t]) > expirationTime)
                        {
                            //object has expired
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("object has expired");
                            Idle.Remove(t);
                            expire(t);
                            //to obtain the default value of a Generic Type
                            t = default(T);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (validate(t))
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection is still open. used back the same object");
                                Idle.Remove(t);
                                Running.Add(t, now);
                                return (t);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //object failed validation
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("object has failed validation");
                                Idle.Remove(t);
                                expire(t);
                                t = default(T);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // no objects avaialable, create a new one
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("no object is available, creating a new one");
                t = create();
                Running[t] = now;
                return (t);
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual void releaseObject(T t)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Running.Remove(t);
            Idle[t] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("release object");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is an implementation of object pooling design pattern, each time a new instance is created by calling this function "GetObject", The below class is a class that override ObjectPooling 's method and integrates with MySql

```
class DatabaseConnection : ObjectPool<MySqlConnection>
{
    private String ConnectionString =
        "datasource=127.0.0.1;" +
        "port=3306;" +
        "username=root;" +
        "password=;" +
        "database=mesa;" +
        "Integrated Security = SSPI;"+
        "Min Pool Size = 1;" +
        "Max Pool Size = 9;" +
        "Connection Lifetime = 600;";

    public DatabaseConnection() : base()
    {
    }

    public override void expire(MySqlConnection o)
    {
        try
        {
            o.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Closing Database Connection Successful");
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Closing Database Connection Unsuccessful");
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                            "MySql Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool validate(MySqlConnection o)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Validating");
        try
        {
            if (o.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Database cannot check current state");
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                            "MySql Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            return false;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected internal override MySqlConnection create()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Database Connection Successful");
            return (mySqlConnection);
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                            "MySql Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            return null;   
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The above class illustrates three override method which are "create" which will create a new instance when the connection is expired , and "expire" this is to close a connection when the connection is already expired. The last function which is to validate whether the current connection is open or not. Now, the below code is a normal class that will associate with object pooling and databas connection.

```
class InputValidation
{
    private DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection();

    //Constructor
    public InputValidation()
    {

    }

    //Destructor
    ~InputValidation()
    {
      //databaseConnection.expire();
    }


    public void CheckForExistingPT_NUM1(String pt)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection1 = databaseConnection.GetObject;

        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM carrier";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection1);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string someStringFromColumnZero = reader.GetString(0);
                string someStringFromColumnOne = reader.GetString(1);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(someStringFromColumnZero + "," + someStringFromColumnOne);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        databaseConnection.releaseObject(connection1);
    }

    public void CheckForExistingPT_NUM2(String pt)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection1 = databaseConnection.GetObject;

        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM carrier";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection1);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string someStringFromColumnZero = reader.GetString(0);
                string someStringFromColumnOne = reader.GetString(1);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(someStringFromColumnZero + "," + someStringFromColumnOne);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        databaseConnection.releaseObject(connection1);
    }

}
```

Now, as you can see from these two functions `CheckForExistingPT_NUM1(String pt)` and `CheckForExistingPT_NUM2(String pt)` actually these two functions just using the same connection to interact with the database instead of close the connection and open a new connection again. Below is a function of main class that implement all the logic.

```
private void AliasButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String PT_NUM = PTNumTextBox.Text;

        InputValidation inputValidation = new InputValidation();

        inputValidation.CheckForExistingPT_NUM1(PT_NUM);

        inputValidation.CheckForExistingPT_NUM2(PT_NUM);

}
```

Below is line of messages that printed out in output box

```
no object is available, creating a new one
The thread 0x994 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Database Connection Successful
801BRWUE,BCM88682CA1KFSBG
U10BRT7E,BCM3450KMLG
release object
Validating
Connection is still open. used back the same object
801BRWUE,BCM88682CA1KFSBG
U10BRT7E,BCM3450KMLG
release object
```

The problem here is the connection will remain idle when there is no instance is created. As you can see from the output box, the connection2 is still remain idle, the connection will be destroy when a new instance is created, how do I close all the idle connections? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code seems unnecessary, because MySQL Connector/NET already [implements its own connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html). The `MySqlConnection` object is just a lightweight wrapper around the underlying socket connection; there is very little benefit to caching and reusing them. (You are likely to be adding more overhead by creating a finalizable `InputValidation` object then you are saving by reusing a `MySqlConnection`.)

> how do I close all the idle connections?

Maybe create a `Timer` that cleans up idle connections on a regular basis, say once a minute? But my recommendation would be to not create this object pool and just rely on the built-in connection pooling.

Note that due to Connector/NET's connection pooling, the underlying network connection to the MySQL Server will remain open. You can call `MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools()` to close all those pooled connections (but note that this will make opening the next DB connection take significantly longer).